# How do you create a live template in Intellij with a variable name inside the abbreviation?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, live-templates

I am trying to create a live template in Intellij by using an abbreviation like:

```
for$index_name$
```

to create the template text:

```
for $index_name$ in
```

For example, I want the abbreviation `forj` to produce `for j in`. I have not found anything regarding this in Intellij's [live template documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/template-variables.html). If such a thing is possible how would it be done?

Comment: Feel free to vote for this request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-228054

Comment: Thanks! I've voted for the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody from [JetBrains](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-228054) has said that

> "Such functionality is currently not available and not very likely to
>   be added in near future, sorry."